# DataTables how to Custom toolbar elements without loss pagelength,button elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I saw this [DataTable Example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) explaining custom toolbar elements.

However, when I set:

```
"dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
```

then my toolbar will lose "pagelength" and button,

How can I Custom toolbar elements without loss pagelength and button elements?

Comment: can you add full code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include `l` in toolbar dom. to get pagelength element.

other built-in table control elements in DataTables are:

`l` - `l`ength changing input control

`f` - `f`iltering input

`t` - The `t`able!

`i` - Table `i`nformation summary

`p` - `p`agination control

`r` - p`r`ocessing display element

similarly use can use markup options to add classes and id's

`<` and `>` - div element

`<"class"` and `>` - div with a class

`<"#id"` and `>` - div with an ID

`<"#id.class"` and `>` - div with an ID and a class

**Below is a code snippet i have used in my datatable to positioning different controls :**

```
dom:" <'row'<'col-sm-4'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-2'l><'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-4'p>>"
```

Comment: Is this helpfull ?

Comment: please support if answer is helpful.

Comment: This is super helpful, THX ALOT FOR THIS